# Call Servlet from an Iframe

Tags: javascript, servlets, iframe

I have an iframe and a form tag in it.I have a javascript from which i want to submit this form to a servlet but nothing happens.it does not direct to servlet.
Need the servlet response on the same Iframe.Any help with this??

```
window.frames['frame1'].document.getElementByName('ctn').value = document.applets[0].getTelephoneNumber();
window.frames['frame1'].document.getElementById('myFormId').submit();
```

Comment: i wonder why you tag this with "jquery" while you dont use jQuery. No java here, either.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to do that. A 3rd Person can fish for login and password.

But its allowed to call javascript functions in a iframe like this:

```
window.frames['frame1'].contentWindow
    .submitNumber(document.applets[0].getTelephoneNumber());
```

So your iframe must contains this:

```
<script> function submitNumber(nr){...}</script>
```